# phpmyadmin access denied after installing manually mysql

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

I tried to install mysql after I already had xampp, I changed the password and now I'm getting this errors when I try to access phpmyadmin

```
        Error
MySQL said: Documentation

#2002 - No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it.
— The server is not responding (or the local server's socket is not correctly configured).
mysqli_real_connect(): (HY000/2002): No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it.
Connection for controluser as defined in your configuration failed.
mysqli_real_connect(): (HY000/2002): No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it.
```

I tried everything, including changing the password in confing.inc.php
and try to reset the password from cmd, when I tried this I got this error:

```
MySQL [(none)]> SET PASSWORD FOR 'root'@'localhost' = PASSWORD('');
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'PASSWORD('')' at line 1
```

Comment: Most likely the newly installed MySQL is being run at boot and therefore nothing you setup in the XAMPP version of MySQL is availabble to you. Uninstall the manually installed version of MySQL

Comment: @RiggsFolly I deletes it and now I get these error (I will edit the question)

Comment: By _deleted it_ I hope you mean _uninstalled it_ Right??

Comment: My next guess would be that you have not now started the XAMPP version of MySQL so there is nothing listening for connections

Comment: yes, I meant uninstalled :), and the next comment was right! I don't know how I forgot this... thank you very much!